# Oracle - synchronise tablespace schema changes to another tablespace from the same database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-replication, tablespace

I am using two tablespaces from the same Oracle database (11g), one is tablespace A, the other is B.

I'd like to set a daily planified task which would alter the tablespace B in order to integrate the changes made to the tablespace A during the day (example: new tables, new columns, triggers or relations).

Has anyone an idea on how to set up such task ?

Thank you very much for your anwers and have a nice day

Comment: This is a strange idea. A tablespace is a logical unit of storage. There is no necessary grouping between one tablespace and the objects which use its segments and another tablespace. A user can have objects on more than one tablespace, a tablespace can host objects from more than one user. A better solution would be to monitor a **schema**, which is conceptually sound and also allows you to track changes to things which don't use a tablespace, such as views, sequences, triggers, etc

Comment: Also, the need to do this sort of monitoring suggests you aren't using source control to store your DDL scripts. Putting DDL into Git or some similar repository might be a better use of your time and energy.